# @Conditional annotation causing BeanCreationException on nested beans

Tags: conditional-statements, spring-4, beancreationexception

I am using Spring 4.x in which I am using @Conditional annotation to control the bean registration.
I have classes defined as given below,

```
@Controller
class SchoolController{
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("studentProcessor")
   private StudentProcessor studentProcessor;
   //Some code
}

@Component("studentProcessor")
class StudentProcessor{
   @Autiwired
   private SportService sportService;
   //Some code
}

@Component
@Conditional(ServiceCondition.class)
class SportService{
//Some code
}

class ServiceCondition implements Condition{
public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
  //Some condition
}
}
```

When I start the Tomcat, I get this exception:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentProcessor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.student.service.SportService com.student.processors.StudentProcessor.sportService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.student.service.SportService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

1. Is this the expected behavior?
2. If not then how do I get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your configuration, `SportService` bean is **loaded based on the conditional implementation** of `ServiceCondition`.

So, if the `matches` method returns `false` for some reason based on your logic, then `SportService` is would not be created and will not be available for autowiring.

That being said, `StudentProcessor` cannot have a concrete `@Autowired` for `SportService`.

I am not fully aware of your requirement, but for you to proceed with this configuration, you need to mark autowiring as optional.

```
@Autiwired
private SportService sportService;
//Some code
```

to

```
@Autiwired(required = false)
private SportService sportService;
//Some code
```

Further, you need to check if the instance is injected or not and then use it.